# Linear transformation given equation of plane in $\mathbb R^3$ and line in $\mathbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm struggling with this question from a past exam…

Find all linear transformations $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2, (x,y,z) \to (u,v)$ which map the plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given by $x+y+z=1$ on the line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $u-2v=2$

I think I understand the normal process (using standard bases to find the coordinate vectors) but can't understand how that works in this instance.

Is the answer that there are no linear transformations because the zero vector is not part of either equation?

Any help or suggestions much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You know that$$T(x,y,z)=(a_{11}x+a_{12}y+a_{13}x,a_{21}x+a_{22}y+a_{23}z),$$for some $a_{11},a_{12},a_{13},a_{21},a_{22},a_{23}\in\mathbb R$. You want them to be such that $T(1,0,0)$, $T(0,1,0)$, and $T(0,0,1)$ all belong to the given line. This means that$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a_{11}-2a_{21}=2\\a_{12}-2a_{22}=2\\a_{13}-2a_{23}=2.\end{array}\right.$$So, the solution is:$$T(x,y,z)=\bigl((2a+2)x+(2b+2)y+(2c+2)z,ax+by+cz\bigr),$$with $a,b,c\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: [+1] Good answer, as are all your answers. It's a pity some users aren't "fair play" and don't even acknowledge by a sentence that they have their answer...